# How to quickly switch between the videos?

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting parameter gender from my client application and using that value (male/female/None) I would like to change the video shown on the display. I have written an if-else loop. But the issue is that there is a lot of delay in switching the video when the gender changes. Is there a more elegant solution? I would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks.

I have tried this code (server side)

```
def getData(self):
    dst = None

    if self.myHandler.items is not None:
        if len(self.myHandler.items.decode('utf-8')) != 0:
            # dst = self.myHandler.items.decode('utf-8')
            output = self.myHandler.items.decode('utf-8')
            dst = json.loads(output) 
            if dst["gender"] == "F":
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture('No.1/women.mp4')
                if (cap.isOpened()== False):
                    print("Error opening video stream or file")
                while(cap.isOpened()):
                    ret, frame = cap.read()
                    if ret == True:
                        cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

                        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                            break                    
                    else: 
                        break        
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            elif dst["gender"] == "M":                  
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture('No.1/men.mp4')                 
                if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
                    print("Error opening video stream or file")
                while(cap.isOpened()):
                    ret, frame = cap.read()
                    if ret == True:
                        cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
                        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                            break
                    else: 
                        break
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()

            elif dst["gender"] == None :
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture('No.1/normal.mov')                 
                if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
                    print("Error opening video stream or file")
                while(cap.isOpened()):
                    ret, frame = cap.read()
                    if ret == True:
                        cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
                        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                            break
                    else: 
                        break
                cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try timing how long this line takes `cv2.Video Capture("someFile.mov")`. If that is what takes a long time when you *"change gender"*, you could try opening all 3 movies at the start into 3 separate `cap` variables and then just reading from the correct one of the 3 whenever the gender changes.

Comment: thanks, it makes sense. I will try it and get back.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried it but it did not make any difference

Comment: Ok, sorry it didn't work, but I hope it was worth a try. I guess you'll need to instrument your code with some timing measurements to see where the delays occur. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to my mind is to move common code to the separate method. At least your program will be having more clear structure:

```
def show_video(file):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error opening video stream or file")
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def get_data(self):
    if self.myHandler.items:
        if len(self.myHandler.items.decode('utf-8')) != 0:
            output = self.myHandler.items.decode('utf-8')
            dst = json.loads(output)

            if dst["gender"] == "F":
                show_video('No.1/women.mp4')
            elif dst["gender"] == "M":
                show_video('No.1/men.mp4')
            elif not dst["gender"]:
                show_video('No.1/normal.mov')
```

Comment: right. Thanks. This is the better way to write the code. But it does not improve the switching speed